# jQuery: How to determine the parent container element id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to obtain the id of the container whose href element was clicked, using jQuery. I know this involves use of the parent() method, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

Here is a snippet of the kind of HTML doc I will be processing:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cntnr_1" class="container">
             <a href="/foo1">foo1</a>
             <a href="/foo2">foo2</a>
             <a href="/foo3">foo3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="cntnr_2" class="container">
             <a href="/foobar1">foobar1</a>
             <a href="/foobar2">foobar2</a>
             <a href="/foobar3">foobar3</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function(){
            //display the url of the clicked on link
            //display the id of the container whose href was clicked on     
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The desired behavior (When a link [href] in a "container" is clicked) is as follows:

1. Display the link of the url clicked on (so I can submit an AJAX POST to the url)
2. Display the id of the container (so I can push the received data back to that id)

Can anyone help with how to obtain the parent container id and the url that was clicked?

**[[Edit]]**

I have posted the actual HTML code I am using here: http://jsfiddle.net/fpPRL/

Comment: First google hit: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.container a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var container_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    alert('the url is "'+ url +'" from the container #' + id);
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Since you tried it on a different html markup (and didn't work), here's a more *universal* solution (see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/fpPRL/1/):

```
$('.container a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var container_id = $(this).parents('.page_container:first').attr('id');
    alert('the url is "'+ url +'" from the container #' + id);
});
```

Comment: actually, this did not work when I used it in my html page. I have posted the actual page here: http://jsfiddle.net/fpPRL/

Comment: Thanks. I'll study your code in more detail to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert('url:' + $(this).attr('href') + ', parent: ' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/zaPhe/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/

```
$('.container a').live('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).parent('.container').attr('id');
    alert( $(this).attr('href') + ' for ' + id );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        parendtID = $this.closest("div").attr("id");
        thisHref = $this.attr("href");
        alert(parentID + thisHref);
    });
});
```